# javascript deferreds, and looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

Premise: I'm attempting to use deferreds to handle calls to a web service, that when completed, process the data, and then moves to the next call set of web calls.   It is a really long convoluted pathway between a CMS, it's widgets, and some javascript/jquery, and some web calls to an internal service.

Whats actually happening: Most of the time it's returning exactly what is expected, perfect output... MOST of the time.  Occasionally it seems if that the .done isn't holding things up correctly before moving on, and some of the results from the second widget end up in first widgets data.   Thus, I expect that the .done portion may not be exactly what i need.

the URLArray works and links everything properly, but for some reason myJSONData doesn't always contain the proper data.  (may contain EXTRA, from subsequent widgets), thus me suggesting that the .done isn't quite doing what i expect.

Can someone help shed some light on what might be wrong.   I mean i can SEE the finish line, and it works... most of the time... and only this one issue left to resolve.

general code:

```
ulContactID.each(function (d) {  
    var URLArray = [];  
    var departmentList = [];  
    // *****************  
    // Get department  
    // *****************  
    var dept;  
    if (d == 0) {  
        dept = $(".departmentClass");  
    } else {  
        dept = $(".departmentClass" + d);  
    }  
    var department = dept.text();  
    // *************************  
    // Set Department Call  
    // *************************  
    if (department != "none" && department !="") {  
        URLArray.push('http://10.171.1.202:5185/api/employees/GetByDepartment?department=' + department);  
    }  
    // *****************  
    //Get Employee List  
    // *****************  
    var employees;  
    if (d == 0) {  
        employees = $(".employeeClass");  
    } else {  
        employees = $(".employeeClass" + d );  
    }  
    var employeeList;  
    employeeList = employees.text().split(",");  
    // ******************  
    //  Set Employee Calls.  
    // ******************  
    employeeList.forEach(function (d){  
        URLArray.push('http://10.171.1.202:5185/api/employees/GetByUserPrincipalName?userPrincipalName=' + d);   
    });  

Ajax Calls to Web service
        $.when.apply($, Do_AjaxCalls(URLArray)).done(function () {  
            URLArray = [];  
            console.log(myJSONData);  
            // This is where the return myJSONData usually works, but not always.
            // and then resets the array before doing another round in the loop if             //needed.  
            });  
            myJSONData = [];  
        });  
    });
```

AJAX calls using deferreds:

```
// *************************  
// Do Ajax Calls  
// *************************  
function Do_AjaxCalls(URLArray) {  
    var requests = [];  
    var arrayCount = URLArray.length;  
    for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {  
        var currURL = URLArray[i];  
        requests.push(
            $.ajax({  
            type: 'Get',  
            url: currURL,  
            dataType: 'jsonp',  
            fail: console.log("Issue on: " + currURL),  
            success: function (result) {  
                if ($.isArray(result)) {  
                    result.forEach(function (d) {  
                        myJSONData.push(d);  
                    });  
                } else {  
                    myJSONData.push(result);  
                }  
            }  
        }))  
    }  
    return requests;  
}
```

edit: minor textual updates.

Comment: You might be getting errors from your ajax calls every now and again. Your `fail` is wrong, so you won't be able to see console logging for it.

Comment: Well, couple things.  
1) The console.log on the fail, most certainly, shows up.   Is it telling me about an error?  no, but that wasn't what i was trying to see.  I was just test when the warning I was getting about a deferred non-error was happening.  
2) in all cases, I'm actually getting all the data i'm supposed to.  The warning happens on both correct and incorrect returns.  the variation is in the return output UL, and since they are processed linearly, i would expect that for some reason the deferredArray.done isn't working appropriately.

Comment: [example output](https://www.screencast.com/t/yduLTUqSIhFU)